# Transfer contribution to other contact

Tags: contributions

Due to an error a bankaccount (iban) was connected to a wrong contact, so several contributions must be transferred to the right contact. What is the procedure for this action?

Comment: Hi - is het gelukt? What method did you end up using?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is extension '[Move Contribution](https://civicrm.org/extensions/move-contribution)' available for moving contribution from one contact to another. Once you have installed the extension transfer can be done through the contact's contribution tab or through a Find Contributions search result action.

HTH

Pradeep

Answer (score 6):

To move a Contribution from one Contact to another only requires a very small edit in your database.

If you have access to phpMyAdmin -> go to the `civicrm_contribution` table and in the `contact_id` column replace the incorrect contact_id with the correct one. If for example we want to move contribution with id=3 from `contact_id = 10` to `contact_id = 750` -> double click in that table cell and replace 10 with 750.

[image]

If you have access to mysql: change the `contact_id` for contribution with id=3:

```
UPDATE civicrm_contribution SET contact_id = 750 WHERE id = 3;
```